# FIle Transfer in Chat (Einstein Bot)

Tags: service-cloud-console, einstein, einstein-chatbot

when i am requesting file from the visitor using einstein bot the user uploads a file under 5mb but it does not show up in the agent chat it shows waiting for visitor.attaching what i am seeing.what is the problem ??[image]

Comment: I am facing similar problem. do you have any workaround/solution for this?